# SQL to XML, from a single column in a table to a customized XML output

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have an Orders table with OrderNumber column as following:

| OrderNumber |
| --- |
| 1111 |
| 1112 |
| 1113 |
| ... |
| 9999 |

Based on all orders in the table I'm trying to create an SQL-XML script to generate the following output, only OrderNumber is taken from the Orders table:

```
<OrderRequest>
        <OrgLookup>
            <OrgName>ABC_INC</OrgName>
        </OrgLookup>
    <OrderLookups>
        <OrderNumberLookup>
            <OrderNumber>1111</OrderNumber> 
        </OrderNumberLookup>
        <OrderNumberLookup>
            <OrderNumber>1112</OrderNumber> 
        </OrderNumberLookup>
        <OrderNumberLookup>
            <OrderNumber>1113</OrderNumber> 
    </OrderNumberLookup>
    .
    .
    .
    .
        <OrderNumberLookup>
            <OrderNumber>9999</OrderNumber> 
        </OrderNumberLookup>
    </OrderLookups>
</OrderRequest>
```

I'm trying it in different ways but end up creating more number of lines than needed. Any help is very much appreciated.

This is what I have been trying:

```
SELECT 
'ABC_INC' AS 'OrgName',
    (
        select
        t1.OrderNumber AS 'OrderNumber'
        for xml path('OrderNumberLookup')
        
    ),
    for xml path ('OrderLookups')
    from [dbo].[Orders] as t1

for xml path ('OrderRequest')
```

It's difficult to get the above XML format.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `, TYPE` clause if you want to use nested `FOR XML`. The `ROOT` clause allows you to nest the whole result in a single node.

You can use `/` within a column name in order to create a single nested node for that column.

```sql
SELECT 
  'ABC_INC' AS [OrgLookup/OrgName],
  (
      SELECT
        o.OrderNumber
      FROM dbo.Orders o      
      FOR XML PATH('OrderNumberLookup'), ROOT('OrderLookups'), TYPE
  )
FOR XML PATH ('OrderRequest'), TYPE
```

A slightly different version with the same result: you can give the nested `FOR XML` a name, and remove the `ROOT`

```sql
SELECT 
  'ABC_INC' AS [OrgLookup/OrgName],
  (
      SELECT
        o.OrderNumber
      FROM dbo.Orders o      
      FOR XML PATH('OrderNumberLookup'), TYPE
  ) AS OrderLookups
FOR XML PATH ('OrderRequest'), TYPE
```

Comment: That's amazing. It worked very well for me. I'm learning a lot with XML in SQL Server and this is really helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Pleasure. Rather than thanking, consider upvoting and/or accepting an answer (by using the check mark)